# Saving Node Voltage For Different Circuit

Tags: simulation, ltspice, voltage-controlled-resistor

I have 2  circuits. The resistance and capacities of the 2. circuit are voltage dependent/controlled from some nodes of the first one, eg. `Rcircuit2= 10*V(C1V1); Q= 50E-10*V(C1V1)`.

I am using LTspice for the simulation.

Now I want to simulate only the first circuit and later the second one (I know you can have/simulate multiple circuits simultaneously, I want to have 2 separate simulations).

How do I store / save the voltages from the first circuit and import them to the second one?

As far as I understood .wave can only store +1/-1 V, which isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

If using the wave export function is not possible (with or without attenuation before/amplification afterwards), then you can also export the results of the simulation as ASCII: select the waveform window, `File > Export data as text`. After that, the newly created file will have the first line identifying which column belongs to which data, e.g. `time  V(x)`. Delete the first line and the text file can be readily used as a PWL file: place a source in the schematic, right-click on it, select `PWL FILE`, choose your newly created text, and use it.